# How are keys in an object literal evaluated?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Here is my function

```
function goldAndSilver(bin) {
    var gold = bin.gold;
    var silver = bin.silver;
    return { gold: gold, silver: silver };
}
```

Why does the first `gold` reference the *name* and the second `gold` reference the *value* when `var gold = bin.gold` has already been encountered in execution context. After the line runs wouldn't `gold = number` always and the return should result in `{5: 5}` instead of `{gold: 5}`?

Comment: What @IrkenInvader said. I imagine you're simply curious about how the code is functioning, but if you actually _want_ `{5: 5}`, I would say that (in most cases) `{gold: 5}` is a far more meaningful object structure.

Comment: The title and tags don't really seem to have anything to do with your actual question. I updated / simplified your question. Feel free to revert if you don't like it.

Answer (score 5):

Using this notation `{ gold: gold, silver: silver }` the word before the colon will always be the name, it never refers to a variable.

If you want to use a variable as the name of an object property that can be done like this:

```
var gold = 5;
var obj = {};
obj[gold] = gold;
```

This results in
`Object {5: 5}`

Comment: Note that JavaScript only uses Strings as object keys, so the resulting object of the code above would be `{"5": 5}`.

Comment: It only uses strings, but its syntax allows for unquoted identifiers, and `5` is a valid property identifier, just as `gold` and `sliver` are.

Comment: Also in browsers that support it you can use Computed Names:[ecma spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer), [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015), `{[gold]:gold}`

Comment: @TimoSta -- Are you sure? When I pop open chromes console and do `var x = {5:5}` - I get `Object {5: 5}` at the log output

Comment: @tymeJV, that is because the console does not show the quotes around the property name. But TimoSta is wrong in that Javascript only uses `String`s as property __keys__, it can also use [Symbols](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type): __All String and Symbol values, including the empty string, are valid as property keys. A property _name_ is a property key that is a String value__. As for numbers: _An integer index is a String-valued property key_

Answer (score 2):

No because objects keys are not calculated by default. The property will be given the exact name as you named it. However, with ES2015 you can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#Computed_property_names) which allow you to name a property using a dynamic value.

(Note that this only works on browsers which support the new syntax):

```js
var gold = 5;
var obj = {
  [gold]: gold
};

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the object notation. Here first word before ':' is key. It is always a string. It is like assigning a name to the value you want to assign. The second one is the value. 
In this notation you cannot assign  a variable as a key. Key will always be constant and a string.

```
{ gold: gold, silver: silver }
is same as
var obj = { 'gold': gold, 'silver': silver }
```

To assign variable as key, you  have to use square bracket notation.

```
 var key1='gold';
 var key2='silver';
 var obj={};
 // assuming gold and silver to defined
 obj[key1]=gold;
 obj[key2]=silver;
```

In both the cases obj are the same. But second format can be used when key names are known prior to assigning values.

For example lets see code to clone an object(one level):

```
function clone(original){
  var clone={};
  for(var key in original){
  // Dont know what is the value of key. So we need to use square
  //bracket. clone.key would be incorrect to use because it would be
  //considered string.

  clone[key]=original[key];
  }
 return clone;
}
```